# Dimension of intersection of spans

Tags: linear-algebra

I am having some trouble with the following problem: being $L_1 = L({(1,2,3,4), (2,2,2,6), (0,2,4,4)})$ and $L_2 = L({(1, 0, -1, 2), (2,3,0,1)})$.

Determine the dimension of $L_1$, $L_2$, $L_1 + L_2$ and $L_1 \cap L_2$.

By row reduction I have found that $L_1$ = $
  \left[ {\begin{array}{ccc}
   1 & 2 & 0 \\
   0 & -2 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & -2 & 4
  \end{array} } \right]
$

This is a basis of $R³$ since it is linearly independent and generates the full span. Indeed, this is equivalent to $<(1,0,0,0), (0,1,0,0), (0,0,0,1)>$ (Is this right?)

Along the same line of reasoning, I get $L_2$ is a basis for $R^2$. Therefore, $dim(L_1)=3$ and $dim(L_2)=2$.

But I don't know how to go on from this point. My reasoning is that $L_1 \cap L_2 = R_3 \cap R_2 = \emptyset$. Therefore, $dim(L_1 + L_2) = 5$; but I don't think this is correct.

Comment: I suppose by $+$ union must be meant, use Gram-Schmidt for the 5 vectors, one Hint: your problem is in a 4d space, so every dimensionality is capped by 4. By the dimension of the intersection following is meant: Your first three vectors define a 3d subspace in $R^4$ and the other two define a 2d subspace in $R^4$. So they have to share at least one spanning vector so dimenisonality of the intersection is larger than 1 (3+2-4=1). Also it cannot be larger than 2. Just try to think in terms of range spaces.

Comment: No, you don’t have a basis of $\mathbb R^3$. You have a basis for a three-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb R^4$.

Comment: @keoxkeox Gram-Schmidt is unnecessary here. Row-reduction will eliminate redundant generating vectors just fine.

Comment: It is more methodical and scalable to use G-S, I am also an avid fan of QR decomposition. @amd is correct, use whatever floats your basis. I like mine orthonormal :)

Comment: G-S requires an inner product.